# How to calculate the integral of the exp of the sum of function handles in a cell

Tags: matlab

I don't know how to calculate the integral of the sum of function handles in a cell. Please see the below examples:

```
f{1} = @(x) x;
f{2} = @(x) x^2;

g = @(x) sum(cellfun(@(y) y(x), f));
integral(@(x) exp(g), -3,3);
```

Error: Input function must return 'double' or 'single' values. Found 'function_handle'.

PS: please don't change the formula, because this is just an example. My real problem is far more complicated than this. It has log and exp of this sum (integral(log(sum), -inf, inf)). So I can't break them up to do the integral individually and sum the integrals.I need to use sum(cellfun). Thank you.

Version: Matlab R2012a

Can anyone help me? Really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add function handles, so anything that tries `f{1}+f{2}+...` would give an error.

But you can compute the integral of the sums like this, evaluating the function values one at a time and adding up the results:

```
function cellsum
  f{1} = @(x) x;
  f{2} = @(x) x.^2;

  integral(@(x)addfcn(f,x), -3, 3)
end

function s = addfcn(f,x)
  s = zeros(size(x));
  for k = 1:length(f)
      s = s + f{k}(x);
end
end
```

Note that `x` will usually be a vector when the `integral` command calls your functions with it.  So your function definitions should be vectorized, .i.e., `x.^2` instead of `x^2`, etc.

Comment: Hi Kavka,Thanks for your help. My real problem is far more complicated than this. It has log and exp of this sum (integral(log(sum), -inf, inf)). So I can't break them up to do the integral individually and sum the integrals.I need to use sum(cellfun)

Comment: @digdeep You did not understand the answer. Kavka is not integrating functions individually; there is just one use of  `integral`. The `addfcn` code can also include taking logarithm of the sum, or whatever formula you want to apply to the functions.